# React: Correct use of useCallback hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

**What I Want To Implement:**

I am fairly new to the `useCallback` and `useMemo` React Hooks, and I'm still figuring out the correct use cases for each hook. Below is my component, which when `props.orangeCountyCasesCityData` changes, all of the values in the array are reduced into a total.

Can someone confirm this is the correct use of `useCallback` and also the correct use in the `useEffect` hook.

**My Logic:**

1. When `props.orangeCountyCasesCityData` changes, the `useEffect` hook is called.
2. If the array length is greater than 1, `calculateTotal` is called within the `useEffect` hook.
3. `calculateTotal` uses the `useCallback` hook, so that reduced value is memoized. Is this correct/am I missing anything?

**Component (Current):**

```
  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check If Data
    if (props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.length >= 1) {
      // All Cases Total
      let allCasesTotal = props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

      // Set Total
      setTotal(allCasesTotal);
    }
  }, [props.orangeCountyCasesCityData]);
```

**Component (Correct Use Of useCallback?):**

```
  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    // Calculate Total
    const calculateTotal = useCallback(() => {
      // All Cases Total
      let allCasesTotal = props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

      // Set Total
      setTotal(allCasesTotal);
    });

    // Check If Data
    if (props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.length >= 1) {
      // Calculate Total
      calculateTotal();
    }
  }, [props.orangeCountyCasesCityData]);
```

**Component (useMemo):**

```
  // Total
  const total = useMemo(() => {
    // Check If Data Exists
    if (props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.length >= 1) {
      // All Cases Total
      let allCasesTotal = props.orangeCountyCasesCityData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

      return allCasesTotal;
    }
  }, [props.orangeCountyCasesCityData]);
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect case for `useMemo`, however looking for some confirmation from hooks expert.

Comment: This would not need a `useCallback`. `useMemo` and `useCallback` are essentially the same thing, `useCallback` is just an easier syntax to memoize functions. Both require a dependency array (like the `useEffect` in your example). In this case if the total is only calculated based off passed in properties and requires no other action based update triggers the whole `useEffect`, `useCallback` and presumably `useState` you have set up can be replaced with a single `useMemo`. [Example of useMemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hkwlsn)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs and the examples! I've updated the question with the component using useMemo. Can you confirm this is the correct way?